# Is there a program that would allow me to access my locally hosted websites like my remote ones?

Tags: website, home-server, localhost, wamp

for example I debug my local website this way

http://localhost/example.com/

Is there a program that would make a more convenient alias for it like for example

http://example.com

forcing my browser to use my local files and not the ones online?

Comment: Think about local hosts entries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find 'localhost' easier to type, fewer keystrokes! It gives you a chance to imagine life before TLDs!

To accomplish what you're asking, you can add a line to your **Hosts** file like:

```
127.0.0.1       example.com
```

This would skip DNS lookup for example.com and go straight to your local IP. [For the location of the Hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file#Content_and_location) on your system, check out the corresponding Wikipedia article.

Comment: Not to be too picky, but if he is running multiple local sites this would require some apache configuration, too.

Comment: I am actually, how would one do that?

Comment: i just found this answer http://superuser.com/questions/81707/how-to-create-a-fake-hostname-in-windows